# JNI/C++ compiling problems

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I'm new to C++ and try to compile a .so file to run it via JNI in Java.

The directory structure of the C++ folder is:

```
/
/lib/ - this contains a .a file = library.a below
/folder1 - this contains the .cpp .h and .o files
```

**Scenario 1:**

I'm running the following:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I$JAVA_HOME/include -Ifolder1/ -I$JAVA_HOME/include/linux -o outputFileName.so inputFileName.cpp -Llib -llibrary.a -fPIC -shared
```

I get the following error:

```
relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

All of the files and the .so object had the -fPIC flag. What's the issue?

**Scenario 2:**

I'm running the following:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -I$JAVA_HOME/include -Ifolder1/ -I$JAVA_HOME/include/linux -o outputFileName.so inputFileName.cpp -shared
```

So without the -L and -l flags.

I get the .so file and put it in /usr/lib with the relevant naming i.e. "lib" prefix. When I run Java program I get:

```
symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/outputFileName.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3...
```

I use c++filt to decompile the symbol and I get a reference to a class like this:

```
namespace::Class::Constructor
```

I checked the .cpp file of the class and the constructor exists.

Help please?

Comment: Please post all the commands used to build the library.  Also, this question should probably be split into two separate questions.

Comment: Wild guess but maybe some name mangling problems - Are function declarations you are running from JAVA wrapped in extern "C" block?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here for a sample code where you can see how JNI can use other shared library.

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/blob/master/recipes/recipeNo023/Makefile

It looks like you refer to some sort of libs that are used by your .so file.

Make sure to have them at your LD_LIBRARY_PATH - not just your JNI library.